# Prove $x^{2 \over 3} \ln(x)$ is uniformly continious

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

Prove $x^{2 \over 3} \ln(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $(1,\infty)$

To my understanding I need to show the derivative is bounded. That will prove uniform continuity. The derivative is:

$$ {2\ln(x) + 3} \over {3x^{1 \over 3}}$$

Now, I need to test the limit of the derivative at $\infty$ but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Does  $\lim _{x\rightarrow 1} x^{\frac{2}{3}} \ln(x)$ exist?

Comment: Yes, and it's value is $0$

Comment: so can you say this is uniformly continuous? There is a result which says If a continuous function $f: (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be extended continuously to $[a,b]$ then it is uniformly continuous... I am not very sure if $b$ can be $\infty$.. I am just giving some idea..

Comment: What if we'll define $g(x) = x - f(x)$, and we'll show $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (1, \infty)$, would it help?

Comment: I do not understand how does this help?

Comment: Your last phrase means you *have* to use l'Hospital's rule or you can **not** ?

Comment: @DonAntonio he can use it.

Comment: @GinKin, I don't think we're allowed to use l'Hospital's rule

Comment: @AndrePoole, he asked if we can use LHR and we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say LHR is forbidden and as GinKin mentioned - Riemann integration is not covered in calc 1. The easiest way of proving the statement is to show that the derivative is bounded.

As AndrePoole found the derivative is $$f'(x)=\frac{2ln(x)+3 }{3x^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Obviously, it is bounded from below by 0 (actually, by 1, but we only need to find a boundary and 0 is easier).

Now, let's define $x:=m^3$ (it is possible because $m\in(1,\infty)$, same as x). We can write $$f'(x)=\frac{2ln(x)+3 }{3x^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{2ln(m^3)+3}{3\cdot{(m^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}}=\frac{6ln(m)+3}{3m}=\frac{2ln(m)}{m}+\frac{1}{m}$$
Now we may use that $\forall x>0 \ : \ ln(x) \le x \rightarrow \frac{ln(x)}{x} \le 1$, thus $\frac{2 ln(m)}{m}+\frac{1}{m} < 2+1=3$.

We found that $0<f'(x)<3$, so the derivative is bounded, therefore the function is uniformly continuous for $x\in(1,\infty)$.

Good day!

Comment: Nice answer. תודה.

Answer (score 3):

Take $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$. It is zero as $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x^\alpha} = 0$ for any  $\alpha > 0$. Proof of this formula is a little lengthy. We have to use definition of $\log(x)$ obtained in the theory of Riemann integratioin. So you shall get $|f'(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $x > G$ (depending on $\epsilon$).

So we are getting $|f'(z)| < \epsilon$ when $x > G$

Now consider $(1,G]$. See $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f'(x) = 1$ according to your calculation. So $f'(x)$ is bounded in $[1,G]$.

Thus ultimately we are getting $|f'(x)| < M$ when $x \in (1, \infty)$

Hope the proof is done.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to take the limit?

Comment: I believe this is perfect... Hope some expert confirm it!

Comment: Happy new year and good evening to both Praphulla, AndrePoole

Comment: @HopelessFool : Happy new year :)

Comment: @AndrePoole you know that "Rienmann integration" will be covered only in calc 2 next semester so how can you accept that ?

Comment: @HopelessFool isn't it enough to show the $f'$ is bounded with taking limits and say that if the derivative is bounded than the function is lipschitz ?

Comment: @GinKin, I think you're right, but can you demonstrate how to take the limit?

Comment: Hint: try to substitute $x=m^3$ and use known limits. It is also imprtant to mention that m is also in $(1,\infty)$. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use LHR on f(x).

Derive twice to get to an expression that go to 0 as x tend to infinity (I got $\frac{2}{x^{\frac 13}}$).

Then if $f'$ is bounded, $f$ is lipschitz thus uniformly continuous.

Comment: Many thanks, are you sure we can use LHR?

Comment: @AndrePoole Yeah! we learned derivation and Shiri proved LHR.

Comment: Of course, but it doesn't **prove** we can use it in ex #12, but if you say so...

Comment: @AndrePoole you can use whatever you've seen proven, I also edited my answer a bit.